# How to make textfield required using listeners

Tags: aem

I have listener over selector to hide and show textfield based upon the selected value. I want to implement the value that will show should be mandatory to fill in. I used allowdBlank to true inside my listener but it didn't work. Below is my listener.

```
function(selection,record,path)
{
var dialog=selection.findParentByType('panel');
var email = dialog.getComponent('email1');
var url = dialog.getComponent('url1');
if(record == 'email'){
    url.hide();
    url.setValue("");
    email.show(); //how to make email manadory  
}
if(record == 'link'){
    email.hide();
    email.setValue("");
    url.show(); 
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried this as well, and if I remember right it is not possible to change the mandatory flag after the component is created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used "allowBlank" on a selectionChanged listener.  I've used it successfully to toggle fields as required/not-required many times.  Here's some working code adapted to your example (I omitted the parts that don't relate to the required field).  It is using the `getField` method instead of getComponent as well:

**Dialog:**

```
<type
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="Type"
    name="./type"
    type="radio"
    xtype="selection">
    <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <email
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="Email"
                value="email"/>
        <url
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="Url"
                value="url"/>
    </options>
    <listeners
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        selectionchanged="function(field,value) { 
                              MyDialog.setRequired(field,value); }"/>
</type>
```

**Listener JavaScript:**

```
MyDialog.setRequired = function(field,value) {
    var dialog = field.findParentByType("dialog"),
        email = dialog.getField('./email1');

    if('url' == value) {
        email.allowBlank = true;
    }else{
        email.allowBlank = false;
    }
};
```